# Create dataframe columns from list with items with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have been searching google and have tried a couple of things but failed to do this. Basically I am pulling data from an api which loads into a json

```
session = requests.Session()
s = session.get(url, headers = headers)
r = s.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r)
print(df)
```

The above code returns a dataframe with one colum where each row is similar to below:

```
{'id': 123456, 'address_id': 23456, 'custo... }
```

I need to convert this into a dataframe with id, address_id,etc. as separate columns.

Note, I don't think I need the first DataFrame, I think the api creates a dictionary of dictionaries as such:

```
{'details': [{'id': 123456, 'address_id': 23456, ...
```

Ideally it would be a performant loop as I will be pulling lots of rows.

Thanks! and apologies for my noob-ness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. Looks like you need to set the values using the details key `'details'`

**Ex:**

```
session = requests.Session()
s = session.get(url, headers = headers)
r = s.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r['details'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Woah that simple! thanks very much!  

As a 2nd question, what if a few a of the columns are also lists, is there any fast way to unpack them into other columns?

Comment: ' columns are also lists,' you mean in the dictionary?

Comment: Accepted!
yeah, within the dictionary some columns are also actually dictionaries - looking to unpack them as well